# Splash screen with alpha channel

Tags: python, splash-screen, autoit

I am trying to create a splash screen window with alpha transparency in Python. It just has to display an image. I was successful with AutoIt but don't have experience with ctypes or win32 API and it seems I have to use them to convert the script to Python. I don't want to rely on an external UI framework.

Is there a way to reproduce [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnO46.png) in Python?

```
#NoTrayIcon
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Change2CUI=y

#include <GDIPlus.au3>
#include <GuiConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$sImage = "C:\My\CODE\PawketApps\pawket\@assets\Multiple alpha.png"
$sXaxis = ""
$sYaxis = ""
$iX_axis = 0
$iY_axis = 0
$iAlphac = 255
$iExitT = 3500

_GDIPlus_Startup()
$hSplashlogo = _GDIPlus_ImageLoadFromFile($sImage)

$SplashGUIlogo = GUICreate("", _GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($hSplashlogo), _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($hSplashlogo), $iX_axis, $iY_axis, $WS_POPUP, BitOR($WS_EX_LAYERED,$WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW))

_SetBitmap($SplashGUIlogo, $hSplashlogo, $iAlphac, _GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($hSplashlogo), _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($hSplashlogo))
GUISetState(@SW_SHOWNA, $SplashGUIlogo)

Local $hTimer = TimerInit()

While 1
    If TimerDiff($hTimer) >= $iExitT Then _Exit()
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc

_GDIPlus_Shutdown()

Func _SetBitmap($hGUI, $hImage, $iOpacity, $n_width, $n_height)
    Local $hScrDC, $hMemDC, $hBitmap, $hOld, $pSize, $tSize, $pSource, $tSource, $pBlend, $tBlend

    $hScrDC = _WinAPI_GetDC(0)
    $hMemDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC($hScrDC)
    $hBitmap = _GDIPlus_BitmapCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap($hImage)
    $hOld = _WinAPI_SelectObject($hMemDC, $hBitmap)
    $tSize = DllStructCreate($tagSIZE)
    $pSize = DllStructGetPtr($tSize)
    DllStructSetData($tSize, "X", $n_width)
    DllStructSetData($tSize, "Y", $n_height)
    $tSource = DllStructCreate($tagPOINT)
    $pSource = DllStructGetPtr($tSource)
    $tBlend = DllStructCreate($tagBLENDFUNCTION)
    $pBlend = DllStructGetPtr($tBlend)
    DllStructSetData($tBlend, "Alpha", $iOpacity)
    DllStructSetData($tBlend, "Format", 1)
    _WinAPI_UpdateLayeredWindow($hGUI, $hScrDC, 0, $pSize, $hMemDC, $pSource, 0, $pBlend, $ULW_ALPHA)
    _WinAPI_ReleaseDC(0, $hScrDC)
    _WinAPI_SelectObject($hMemDC, $hOld)
    _WinAPI_DeleteObject($hBitmap)
    _WinAPI_DeleteDC($hMemDC)
EndFunc
```

A script by ChatGPT just creates a white opaque box:

```py
import ctypes
import time
import win32con
from PIL import Image
import ctypes.wintypes

# Adding Graphic & Image Libraries

# Constants
WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x80
ULW_ALPHA = 2

# Declaring Variables For Global Scope
sImage = "C:\\My\\CODE\\PawketApps\\pawket\\@assets\\Multiple alpha.png"
sXaxis = ""
sYaxis = ""
iX_axis = 0
iY_axis = 0
iAlphac = 255
iExitT = 3500

# Start Image Manipulating Library & Load Image
hSplashlogo = Image.open(sImage)

# Create GUI Window
SplashGUIlogo = ctypes.windll.user32.CreateWindowExW(
    0, "STATIC", "", win32con.WS_POPUP | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
    iX_axis, iY_axis, hSplashlogo.width, hSplashlogo.height,
    0, 0, 0, None
)
ctypes.windll.user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(SplashGUIlogo, 0, iAlphac, ULW_ALPHA)

# Load the image and draw it on the window
hdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(SplashGUIlogo)
hdcMem = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)
hBitmap = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, hSplashlogo.width, hSplashlogo.height)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap)

bitmap_data = hSplashlogo.tobytes()
ctypes.windll.gdi32.SetBitmapBits(hBitmap, len(bitmap_data), bitmap_data)

# Define the BLENDFUNCTION structure
class BLENDFUNCTION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("BlendOp", ctypes.c_byte),
        ("BlendFlags", ctypes.c_byte),
        ("SourceConstantAlpha", ctypes.c_byte),
        ("AlphaFormat", ctypes.c_byte),
    ]

blend_func = BLENDFUNCTION()
blend_func.BlendOp = 0
blend_func.BlendFlags = 0
blend_func.SourceConstantAlpha = 255
blend_func.AlphaFormat = 1

ctypes.windll.user32.UpdateLayeredWindow(
    SplashGUIlogo, hdc, None, None, hdcMem, None, 0, ctypes.byref(blend_func), ULW_ALPHA
)

# Show the window
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(SplashGUIlogo, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
ctypes.windll.user32.UpdateWindow(SplashGUIlogo)

# Message loop
msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
while ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
    ctypes.windll.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
    ctypes.windll.user32.DispatchMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg))
    time.sleep(0.01)

# Cleanup
ctypes.windll.user32.ReleaseDC(SplashGUIlogo, hdc)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.DeleteDC(hdcMem)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.DeleteObject(hBitmap)
hSplashlogo.close()
```